# Как вывести записи до даты которых осталось n дней?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе mysql есть колонка с еще не наступившей датой в формате date(Y-m-d) как составить запрос, чтобы вывести записи, до которых осталось n (например 5) дней? Спасибо!

Comment: Ровно 5 дней (с точностью до секунды), или не менее 5, или диапазон ? А так берите дату `now() + interval 5 day` и сравнивайте с ней все что нужно

Comment: 5 дней и менее...

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно почитать об INTERVAL. Это будет выглядеть примерно так

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```